# Set authentication in Swagger if there is a custom login

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to configure swagger for my API, but I don't know how to set the authorization because the app has a different flow.

Application flow: FE-> request to BE -> if there are not specific cookies -> return 401 -> if 401 is returned FE redirect to login page that set some cookies.

How could I redirect to the login page from swagger if cookies are not set?

Comment: you want to redirect to login page in API ?

Comment: You don't redirect Swagger, you tell swagger how an authorisation is performed, and the user presses the Authorize button.

Comment: yes, @CodingMytra

Comment: And which login page you want to redirect ? Any third party provider ? You can do this via a.middleware which can check for this cookies and if not found then you can redirect to any login page you want